# Dart 2 libraries in one lib folder causing type 'X' is not a subtype of type 'X'

Tags: dart

I have a following problem:
In my application, I have web and lib folders.
Lib folder is supposed to contain utility libraries.
Example:

lib/my_lib.dart

```dart
library my_lib;
part 'src/person.dart';
```

lib/my_lib1.dart

```dart
library my_lib1;
import 'my_lib.dart';
part 'src/other.dart';
```

In my_lib1, I want to use classes defined in my_lib

the classes are as follows:

lib/src/person.dart

```dart
part of my_lib;
class Person {
}
```

lib/src/other.dart

```dart
part of my_lib1;
class Other {
  Person p;
  Other(this.p) {
   print(p);
  }
}
```

Now, in web/testpackage.dart

```dart
import 'package:TestPackage/my_lib.dart';
import 'package:TestPackage/my_lib1.dart';

void main() {
  Person p = new Person();
  Other o = new Other(p);
}
```

Fails with:

```
Exception: type 'Person' is not a subtype of type 'Person' of 'p'.
Other.Other (package:testpackage/src/other.dart:7:14)
```

How should I structure my project to prevent that?
My libraries are local to the app, and I don't really want to develop them separately for my toy project.

Comment: have you imported `my_lib` in `my_lib1` ?

Comment: Good point, I somehow forgot it when editing the question, but it was there. Updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem in that the your library `my_lib` is a `public`library and anyone (and you, of course) can use it elsewhere outside of `lib` directory.

In this case it must be imported (becuase it's a public library) always as the package library.

To solve this this problem you must change your source code.

From this `lib/my_lib1.dart`

```dart
library my_lib1;
import 'my_lib.dart';
part 'src/other.dart';
```

To this `lib/my_lib1.dart`

```dart
library my_lib1;
import 'package:TestPackage/my_lib.dart';
part 'src/other.dart';
```